# Why its not necessary to have abstract classes to have abstract method

Tags: java

I have searched for the exact answer but not able to find satisfactory way to understand the actual cause. Why  abstract class have no issue without abstract method? What is different scenarios in which  we should write abstract method  inside a abstract class and in which we didn't?

Comment: Someone should vote for reopening. @Saiprateek: Let's pretend we have an abstract class `Person`. It implements everything a person can do and what defines a person (for your project), like a name, an age etc. Now every implementation of a person sets the data of that person and inherits every ability of the parent class (e.g. `Public class Thomas extends Person` or `public class Maria extends Person`). Now it is possible to create new intances of these sub classes without allowing the program to create new and unwanted persons (i.e. `new Person("name");` is not possible).

Comment: Your title is back to front. It *is* necessary for a class with abstract methods to be declared `abstract.` It isn't necessary for an abstract class to have abstract methods.